# Mysql query throw the 1054 unknown column error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my Mysql query throw the 1054 unknown column interleaving.pdf?

```
SELECT user_id,doc_id,name
FROM `get_edoc_details`
WHERE user_id=290
  AND doc_id=1
  AND name=interleaving.pdf;
```

Comment: You need to add quotes around interleaving.pdf.  `And name = 'interleaving.pdf';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enclose the value of the field in quotes as it is a string.

```
SELECT user_id,doc_id,name FROM `get_edoc_details`
WHERE user_id=290 AND doc_id=1 AND name='interleaving.pdf';
```

Comment: The table name was in backticks.  That is not an issue.